# Vue keep 2 components data in sync when delete item

Tags: vue.js

not sure i'm going about this the correct or best way.

Basically I have got the following data:

```js
surrounding: {
    data: [
        { id: 1, name: 'test' },
        { id: 2, name: 'test' },
        { id: 3, name: 'test' }
    ],
    loading: false
}
editingLocation: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'location 1',
    surrounding: [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

This data is within `Locations` component, I have then got another component (`Surrounding`) which will manipulate this data, my `Locations` component only needs to keep `editingLocation` in sync so when you assign a surrounding it updates the array.

```js
export default {
        props: {
            editingLocation: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => { return {} }
            },
            surrounding: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => { return {} }
            }
        }
```

My issue is within `Surrounding` component I have the ability to add a new `surrounding` and to delete a `surrounding`. Which then of course needs to update the `Surrounding` component AND the `Locations` component, but of course if you delete one a loop is needed to remove the ID from all the `locations` with that ID within the array.

```js
toggle: function(item) {
    const self = this;

    item.saving = true;

    Axios.post("endpoint", item).then(response => {

        item.saving = false;

        /**
         * Success
         */
        if (response.status === 200 && (response.data.attached && response.data.detached)) {
            if (response.data.attached.length) {
                this.editingLocation.surrounding.push(item.id);
            }

            if (response.data.detached.length) {
                let index = this.editingLocation.surrounding.indexOf(item.id);
                if (index > -1) {
                    this.editingLocation.surrounding.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }

            return;
        }
```

As you can see the toggle method toggles the prop `editingLocation`, but of course this doesn't get passed back to my `Locations` component because it's a prop.

My second issue is when I delete a `surrounding`, I need to remove this from all the `locations` within my `Locations` component:

```js
Axios.post("endpoint", item).then(response => {

    if (response.status === 200) {
        item.deleting = false;

        if (response.data.success) {

            let index = this.surrounding.data.map(function(e) {
                return e.id;
            }).indexOf(item.id);
            let locationIndex = this.editingLocation.surrounding.indexOf(item.id);

            this.surrounding.data.splice(index, 1);
            this.editingLocation.surrounding.splice(locationIndex, 1);

            self.$emit('surrounding-removed', item.id);
        }
```

This is how I pass the data to my `Surrounding` component:

```js
<legacy-surrounding-locations :editing-location="editing"
                              :surrounding="surrounding"
                              :locations="locations"
                              @surrounding-removed="deletedSurrounding($event)"
                              @close="surroundingDisplay = false"></legacy-surrounding-locations>
```

And this is the `deletedSurrounding` method I have at the moment:

```js
deletedSurrounding: function(id) {
    Object.keys(this.locations.data).forEach(key => {
        let index = this.locations.data[key].surrounding.indexOf(id);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.locations.data[key].surrounding.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone help me out with this logic to get it right and the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the simplest approach in this situation is to think of component communication in this way: Parent components pass state to their children via props, and children can communicate changes back up to parents via events.

The Vue documentation has pretty solid examples on this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events).

---

In general what I would do is make your `<Surrounding />` component trigger an event for both attaching and detaching to it's location, passing in the needed data only and then the parent component, `<Locations />` in this case, would do the actual heavy lifting like what you wrote here:

```js
if (response.data.attached.length) {
    this.editingLocation.surrounding.push(item.id);
}

if (response.data.detached.length) {
    let index = this.editingLocation.surrounding.indexOf(item.id);
    if (index > -1) {
        this.editingLocation.surrounding.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

And since `<Locations />` is passing this state down to `<Surrounding />` via props, it would be updated immediately.

---

Unless of course these two components aren't in a Parent/Child relationship in which case you either need to lift the state up to a higher component or consider using some sort of global state solution - such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). But that's overkill if these components are setup in a simple Parent/Child relation.